# What cronjob takes care of running a Scheduled Import in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cron, product-import

I don't understand how scheduled import processes are starting.

I don't find a matching cronjob in Magento_ScheduledImportExport, only a cleaning job:

```
<job name="magento_scheduled_import_export_log_clean" instance="Magento\ScheduledImportExport\Cron\ScheduledLogClean" method="execute" />
```

Weirdly, the only thing I found that seems to take care of scheduled imports is a call to `processScheduledOperation()` in the controller `Magento\ScheduledImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Scheduled\Operation\Cron`:

```
/** @var \Magento\ScheduledImportExport\Model\Observer $result */
$result = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\ScheduledImportExport\Model\Observer::class)
                ->processScheduledOperation($schedule, true);
```

But I can't find a place where this controller would be called automatically.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it.

The job_code is `scheduled_operation_ID` with ID being the ID of the profile you created in the backend.

I did not have time to find how the job is added to the `cron_schedule` table but I know it's first added as a setting in the `core_config_data` table by `_addCronTask()` when the import profile is saved in the backend:

```
Magento\ScheduledImportExport\Model\Scheduled\Operation::_addCronTask()
```

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path like '%scheduled_operation_%';
+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                                                          | value                                                                   |
+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1004 | default |        0 | crontab/default/jobs/scheduled_operation_1/schedule/cron_expr | 40 18 * * *                                                             |
|      1005 | default |        0 | crontab/default/jobs/scheduled_operation_1/run/model          | Magento\ScheduledImportExport\Model\Observer::processScheduledOperation |
+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Once saved as a setting (**and the config cache emptied!**), some other process detects it and add the new job in the `cron_schedule` table.

As a side note, the cronjob is set in the `default` group, which checks for new jobs only once every 15 minutes. Which means that setting a new import profile to run 5 minutes from now would never work. You either have to update the "refresh rate" of the group in `Store > Advanced > System > Cron (Scheduled Tasks) > Cron configuration options for group:default` to 1 minutes (path is `system/cron/default/schedule_generate_every`) or simply set your profile to run 15+ minutes later.